# Check the conditions on the rows having same ids in sql server

Tags: sql, join

I have a table as below

```
Id     |  CompanyName
---    |  ---
100    |  IT
100    |   R&D
100    |   Financial
100    |  Insurance
110    |  IT
110    |  Financial
110    |  Product Based
111    |  R&D
111    |  IT
```

The table contains the data like the above structure but contains thousands of ids like these

I want to find out all the ids in which all the company names are IT and R&D.If for any of the ids the company name is not in neither IT not R&D then dont consider those ids.
e.g. id 100 cannot be in this list because it has extra company name as Financial but  id 111 will be considered because all the companies are IT and R&D

Any help?

Comment: Which database/version are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select id
from t
having sum(case when CompanyName not in ('IT', 'R&D') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when CompanyName in ('IT', 'R&D') then 1 else 0 end) = 2;  -- use "> 0" if you want either one.
```

Note:  This assumes that you don't have duplicates in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
  sum(case when CompanyName='IT' OR CompanyName='R&D' then 1 else 0 end) as c1
from t
group by id
having count(*)=2 and c1=2
```

Comment: it is not like that for each id ,IT and R&D should be there.It should work like for each id number of companies is not a concern we have to check whether all those companies should be in IT or R&D.Because your case will not work if for any id there is only one company which is IT then it should work.Your case is only working that all companies should have mandatory IT and R&D which is not the case.All the companies should be any  of IT or R&D

Comment: Ok `having c1>0` should work or `having count(*)= c1 and count(*)>0`.

Comment: but if the combination is IT and Insurance then sum will be 1 and according to c1>0 will pass but there is another company as Insurance but all the companies can either be IT or R&D,therefore,it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM companies
WHERE 
    Id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Id
        FROM companies
        WHERE 
            CompanyName != 'IT'
            AND CompanyName != 'R&D'
    )
;
```

**Subquery**: Select all records  - only `Id`, distinctly - with `CompanyName` different from "IT" and "R&D".

**Main query**: Select all records  - only `Id`, distinctly - which are not in the prior list.

**Results**: **111**

---

Tested on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) with option "*MS SQL Server 2014*" and schema syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE companies
    ([Id] int, [CompanyName] varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO companies
    ([Id], [CompanyName])
VALUES
    (100, 'IT'),
    (100, 'R&D'),
    (100, 'Financial'),
    (100, 'Insurance'),
    (110, 'IT'),
    (110, 'Financial'),
    (110, 'Product Based'),
    (111, 'R&D'),
    (111, 'IT')
;
```

Comment: Thats what i needed.Thank u.

Comment: @Ritesh You are welcome. If it was your solution, please check the answer as "accepted" (the green ckeck mark under the votes number). This way can other users benefit from the right answer too. Bye.